# android unable to start receiver not yet implemented

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, runtime-error

I am wanting to start a `service` (CheckTime) when the phone finishes booting. This appears to work, but my app immediately crashes. I get the following error "`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.alarmtest.MyReceiver: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented`". I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to solve this problem. I am unsure if I have left something out of the `manifest` or not (I am fairly new to developing for android).
This is my code for MyReceiver. (the log.d for this appears)

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public MyReceiver() {   
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, CheckTime.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
        Log.d("evan alarm", "Started on Launch, android autostart");
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }
}
```

and the code for CheckTime (the log.d for this never appears)

```
public class CheckTime {
      public void loglab(){
      Log.d("evan alarm", "We are now in CheckTime");
      }
}
```

and finally the manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alarmtest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service 
        android:name="com.example.alarmtest.MyService" >
        <intent-filter 
            android:label="com.example.alarmtest.MyService">
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.example.alarmtest.CheckTime" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.alarmtest.AlarmActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.alarmtest.ChangeTime"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_change_time" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.AlarmTest.AlarmActivity" />
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.alarmtest.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
```

That's the last line of your receiver.  You're throwing it yourself.

Comment: Lol Same, That's why came here.

Answer (score 4):

remove this line

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
```